# JOLT manipulations with extracting values from array

Tags: json, jolt

Have JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 107110685,
    "rows": [
      {
        "date": "2022-07-05",
        "goals": []
      },
      {
        "date": "2022-07-06",
        "goals": []
      }
    ],
    "total": {
      "goals": []
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 107111205,
    "rows": [
      {
        "date": "2022-07-15",
        "goals": [
          {
            "conversion_type": "postclick",
            "cpa": "318.9"
          },
          {
            "conversion_type": "postview",
            "cpa": "79.73"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "date": "2022-07-16",
        "goals": [
          {
            "conversion_type": "postview",
            "cpa": "23.61"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "total": {
      "goals": [
        {
          "conversion_type": "postview",
          "cpa": "42.77"
        },
        {
          "conversion_type": "postclick",
          "cpa": "363.55"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I want to grab values from goals array and match it with `id` and `date.
I'm stuck with this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "rows": {
          "*": {
            "goals": {
              "*": "[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I also need to add `id` and `date` fields to result to get:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 107111205,
    "date": "2022-07-15",
    "conversion_type": "postclick",
    "cpa": "318.9"
  },
  {
    "id": 107111205,
    "date": "2022-07-15",
    "conversion_type": "postview",
    "cpa": "79.73"
  },
  {
    "id": 107111205,
    "date": "2022-07-16",
    "conversion_type": "postview",
    "cpa": "23.61"
  }
]
```

Also will be good if array `goals` is empty, then we should ignore it to avoid rows only with `id` and `date` in result. But still it's okay, if in final result will appear rows like:

```json
{
  "id": 107110685,
  "date": "2022-07-16"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to determine ***the common nodes***( **`&3`** and **`&1`** which are indices of **`rows`** and **`goals`** respectively ) while roaming **within the indices of the *goals* array** (*the empty ***goals*** will automatically be eliminated as performing this*) such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "rows": {
          "*": {
            "goals": {
              "*": {
                "@(4,id)": "&3.&1.id",
                "@(2,date)": "&3.&1.date",
                "*": "&3.&1.&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Edit** : *The following one might be considered for such a vast input(as lately commented below) which has multiple objects with non-empty **goals** array in it :*

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "rows": {
          "*": {
            "goals": {
              "*": {
                "@(4,id)": "&3.&1.id",
                "@(2,date)": "&3.&1.date",
                "*": "&3.&1.&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "[&2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "[&].&1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you! It works very well with this example, but... It's not working with full file. I can't attach it here, but I can provide pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/zMZFMX6e With this file is stores values as arrays. Can you please check it?

Comment: Just sent an email!

Comment: I'm still struggling with some files. I send another email. Sorry for bothering you!

Comment: Hi @hieshkis . You can add the following two extra specs as a tail to the second group of specs within the answer : `,
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
  }` Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks! But with this spec I lost data. In example which I sent with email I expect 5 rows, but got 4. No nulls now, but instead null I expect data.

Comment: Hi @hieshkis . Can you send your expected output to my email as well ?

Comment: Just sent an email!